# How do I do something if a label is moved to a certain cordinates?

Tags: java, swing

I am using `label.setLocation(x,y)` and I was wondering how do I do something if the label goes to a certain `x` or `y` coordinate? Please make the code understandable and pretty simple since I don't want to get anymore confused that I am right now :) Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to create your own label and override the `setLocation` method:

```
public class MyLabel extends JLabel {
    @Override
    public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
        super.setLocation(x, y);

        //Check the X and Y and do something accordingly.
    }
}
```

Comment: @Takisp22: Sometimes we tend to overthink things ;)